# The web browser address bar makes Windows Asterisk sound every time I press enter

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a web browser, but the web browser address bar makes Windows Asterisk sound every time I press enter. I don't want the system to make that sound every time I press enter.

I didn't add a play sound code or something else, or the system think it's an error so it makes the sound? (Sorry, I'm new to .NET and C#)

Here are part my codes:

```cs
        private void txtUrl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
                browser.Load(txtUrl.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Use the KeyDown event instead, where you can call `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` to prevent the beep.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `KeyDown` event to monitor "Enter".

```
private void txtUrl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        // do some operation
}
```

Besides, you need to modify the TextBox properties, `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoCompleteSource`.

```
txtUrl.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
txtUrl.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.HistoryList;
```

Comment: It still beeps though

Comment: I tested it on another machine, and it also works fine. What is the type of your project? Or, could you provide a simple sample that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @RaymondHsu The same environment with yours. Any sample to reproduce the issue?